# GCP Load Balancer/Backend is unable to server 5000 concurrent user requests

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I am setting up a snowplow application on GCP cloud where we are expecting to receive around 80 to 100M user requests per day. I have completed the setup and the application is working fine but while load testing using loader.io we observed that the application is unable to serve even 5000 users/sec and the load balancer is returning with error 502(Backend_server_error). I am unable to understand why I am getting this error even though memory and cpu utilisation are not even 10% utilised.

Configurations:

Instance: 4 instances behind Autoscaling (2 cpu, 8 gb RAM) - autoscaling not happening as utilisation is not reaching threshold

Load Balancer used: HTTPS Application load Balancer

OS type : CentOs 7

Comment: if you got 502, then it is not LoadBalancer who is unable to serve, but backend. If you can't saturate CPU, it means that your application can't scale vertically and you have bottleneck somewhere in application. I doubt someone will answer your problem without more details. You should have some debugging/tracing/profiling metrics in your application to help you find the problem.

Comment: 2 CPU, 8 GB for 5000 users/sec? My iPhone has more power. Start by measuring memory, cpu, disk, and network loads. Then design a system that can handle that traffic. You state `Never autoscaled as utilisation is low`, but you receive 502 errors.

Comment: How many connexion accept an instance? If you have a soft limitation on that, and you can handle, let's say only 100 connections per VM, the CPU is low, the ram is low, and you don't scale out. however, you are limited and your backend can't serve traffic.

Comment: Could you please suggest how could I tune instance to allow maximum connection ?